# Android Studio, Gradle, how to use external library sources?

Tags: android-studio, gradle, libgdx, libraries, overlap2d

I'm not good about gradle, external libraries, and how that works. I have a specific problem, with libgdx and overlap2d libraries but my question is more about external libraries in general. So, let's go :

As I said, I'm using libgdx and overlap2d in android studio. There is an issue in overlap2d and someone fixed it. Explanation [here](http://overlap2d.com/forums/topic/issue-rotation/). My first question is : how can I get this fix ? When I read the post it seems that the solution has been merged to the main branch, but I don't have it.

If I understood right, gradle downloads the external libraries to build the project. Am I right ? Should I do something special to force gradle to reload the libraries or is that automatic ? If so, why do I not see my problem fixed ?

I have other questions, but I'll ask them depending on the first answers.
Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you import the dependency with Gradle through the repository cloud you can go `tools->android->Sync project with Gradle files`. But the fix you are talking about might not be merged with the dependency project you linked with. There might be a new repository that includes the fix (new version), look for a new version and just change the URL in your Gradle file to the new version. Android studio will ask if it should perform a Gradle sync for you when you change Gradle related files.

If you have the library as a module inside your project you can just pull the new version from Git, replace it with your current library and `tools->android->Sync project with Gradle files`.

Comment: Thank you. Apparently, there is no release available with that fix. As it is open source, can I get the library source, create the right package, and remove overlap2d from gradle.build ?

Comment: Yep you have to download the trunk of the lib where the fix has been comitted and then build the source as a part of your project or at least build it once and use the output jar or whatever in your project. But this will all be local and no more remote repo will be used for this lib.

Comment: I just made it !!! The first time I've tried. I thought I would have more problems. Tonight I'll be less stupid when going to bed. Thanks.